# Apply _.set with _.each in lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to be able to set a property on all objects inside of an array like this:

```
var items = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }];

_.each(items, set('a', 4));

// result should be [{ a: 4 }, { a: 4 }, { a: 4 }]
```

I tried to accomplish this by using `_.rearg` on `_.set` to change the parameter that takes the object to the last one like this:

```
var set = _.rearg(_.set, [2, 0, 1]);
```

However, I cannot get `_.curry` to work on top of calling `_.rearg`.

```
var set = _.curry(_.rearg(_.set, [2, 0, 1]));

set('a', 3, { a: 4 })
// returns Object {a: 3} correctly

set('a', 3)
//returns undefined, should be a function
```

So the desired result of being able to call it like this `set('a', 3)({ a: 2 })` throws an error because it does not return a function.

How do I accomplish this using lodash? I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`_.curry`](https://lodash.com/docs#curry) function accepts an argument `arity` that you should probably set to `3`:

```
_.curry(func, [arity=func.length])
```

> Creates a function that accepts arguments of `func` and either invokes `func` returning its result, if at least `arity` number of arguments have been provided, or returns a function that accepts the remaining `func` arguments, and so on. The `arity` of func may be specified if `func.length` is not sufficient.

The result from `_.rearg` has a length value of zero but the underlying function requires three parameters, so you will need to specify that manually:

```
var set = _.curry( _.rearg(_.set, [2, 0, 1]), 3 );
```

Here's a live demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbgmPq

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if your items is

```
var items = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }];
```

then for lodash _.each and _.set, it would be like this

```
_.each(items, function(item){
    _.set(item, 'a', 4);
});
```

what you are trying to do is, looking up a property 4 on item a, where it doesn't know when a is or 4 is. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through the list of items and using _.set on each item works.

```
_.map(items,function(item){_.set(item,'a',5)});
```

or

```
_.each(items,function(item){_.set(item,'a',5)});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKLmbd?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with [rearg()](https://lodash.com/docs#rearg) comes when you have to read your code six months later - deciphering the argument positions is cumbersome. Combining [unary()](https://lodash.com/docs#unary) and [partialRight()](https://lodash.com/docs#partialRight) gives a much clearer intent:

```
_.each(items, _.unary(_.partialRight(_.set, 'a', 4)));
```

Comment: I see your point, but that syntax is much harder to look at. You'll only have to write `set` once, but you'll have to redo `_.unary(_.partialRight(_.set ... ))` all over the place. That seems less clear and harder to maintain to me.

Answer (score 0):

I used `_.partial`

```
const _ = require('lodash')

const __ = {
    each: bindEach,
    set: bindSet,
    setEach: bindSetEach,
}

function bindArg(func, ...bindArgs) {
    return _.partial(func, _, ...bindArgs)
}

function bindEach(...eachArgs) {
    return bindArg(_.each, ...eachArgs)
}

function bindSet(...setArgs) {
    return bindArg(_.set, ...setArgs)
}

function bindSetEach(...setArgs) {
    return bindEach(bindSet(...setArgs))
}

module.exports = __
```

```
const __ = require('./bindArg')

test('setEach', () => {
    expect(__.setEach('c', 3)([{a: 1}, {b: 2}])).toEqual([{a: 1, c: 3}, {b: 2, c: 3}])
})
```